# ¿Deberían las etiquetas [import] e [importación] ser sinónimas?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Resulta que tenemos dos etiquetas parecidas:

- [import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) generalmente para la instrucción `import` de Python para importar paquetes.
- [importación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importaci%c3%b3n) para el concepto en sí de importar.

También existía [importar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importar) con 7 preguntas así etiquetadas pero las he quitado.

La idea inicial sería que [import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) se renombrara a [python-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-import) para que quedara bien diferenciado. Ahora bien, hay otras preguntas que lo usan legítimamente en otros lenguajes como JavaScript, tipo [¿Cómo usar import en JS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/318007/83).

Por ello, se me ocurren dos opciones:

1. Juntar ambas etiquetas.
2. Definir [importación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importaci%c3%b3n) para el caso genérico de importar datos y utilizar nombres específicos según tecnología, dejando [python-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-import), [javascript-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-import), etc.

Comment: En SO optaron por la segunda opción, y yo me inclinaría por ella. Veremos si hay mas opiniones sobre el tema.

Comment: Sí, a mí me gusta más también @Pikoh. Daría más trabajo de reetiquetar, pero a la larga sería más útil

Comment: A mí también me gusta más la dos :)

Comment: oye pues voy reetiquetando según lo que todos los que hemos comentado hemos acordado, @Pikoh. No sé si después de esta limpia deberíamos mapear [tag:import] a [tag:importación].

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' me parece estupendo. Acabo de fusionar import con importacion. Ahora tar vez si es un import especifico, deberia modificarse el tag por import-python, import-java...o lo que corresponda

Comment: Informe de estado en lo referente a Python, que es lo que me duele XD, a partir de los [comentarios de fedorqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/285536/15089]) (gracias por el aviso :)), he intentado reetiquetar y limpiar un poco todas las publicaciones con la etiqueta.

Comment: Cuatro he dejado con la etiqueta [importación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+importaci%c3%b3n) (relativo a importación de datos), 34 reetiquetadas a [python-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+importaci%c3%b3n), dos directamente marcadas como duplicadas y unas tantas enviadas a cola de cierre por otros motivos (generalmente por "no reproducible").  Añadida orientación de uso y wiki de etiqueta. Quedan 52 por revisar (si alguien no lo ha hecho ya) relacionadas con otros lenguajes, si tengo algo de tiempo seguiré con ello...

Comment: Ostras muchas gracias @FJSevilla. Acabo de reetiquetar el resto de preguntas de [tag:importación] que quedaban, publico respuesta con el detalle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como se acordó en los comentarios, finalmente se ha separado en distintas:

- [importación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/importaci%c3%b3n) queda como etiqueta para el *proceso* de importación de datos, mientras que se ha creado una serie de etiquetas `lenguaje-import` para el uso de `import` en un lenguaje determinado:
- [python-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-import) millones de gracias a FJSevilla por [crearla, reetiquetar e incluso definir su wiki](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4700/deber%C3%ADan-las-etiquetas-import-e-importaci%C3%B3n-ser-sin%C3%B3nimas?noredirect=1#comment19371_4700).
- [java-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-import)
- [javascript-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-import)

Me queda la duda con estas preguntas, que no sé si necesitarían de una etiqueta [laravel-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-import) pues entiendo que es una función propia de Laravel (PHP no la tiene):

- [Laravel Importar archivo de Excel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/281722/83)
- [¿Forma correcta de importar js de liberias en laravel con laravel mix?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/310408/83)
- [Importar una hoja especifica (Laravel excel)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/313850/83)
- [Laravel excel como retornar datos a la funcion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/346986/83)

Y luego está [No me toma una variable (SASS) proveniente de otro archivo SCSS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/238016/83) que no sé si merecería una etiqueta [css-import](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-import).

**Ahora es tarea de todos mantener las etiquetas limpias y consistentes.**

Comment: En las de Laravel, las tres del Excel yo las dejaría con `importación`, al menos el criterio que yo he seguido es, si es una pregunta sobre dudas o errores sobre la importación de la propia librería  (`maatwebsite-excel` en éste caso) correspondería la susodicha `laravel-import`, pero si es un problema relacionado con su uso y la importación de los datos en si ("¿como importo x columna?","¿x hoja?", etc?) lo considero importación de datos. Similar a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'"  vs "pandas.read_excel no me carga la hoja correcta". Con las otras estoy también indeciso...

Comment: Vale, estoy de acuerdo. Sobre las que quedan pendientes, haré un ping a Cedano o algún otro usuario potente en esas etiquetas, a ver qué sugieren