# Juntemos [ordenación], [ordenamiento], [sort] y [sorting]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Las siguientes etiquetas existen y no son sinónimas:

- [ordenación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordenaci%c3%b3n) (13 preguntas)
- [ordenamiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordenamiento) (123)
- [sort](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sort) (23)
- [sorting](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting) (apenas 2)

Propongo juntarlas y usar *ordenación* como principal. Al este del Atlántico suena más natural. ¿Qué os parece?

Comment: propongo ordenamiento por dos razones 1 tiene mas preguntas, 2 de donde yo vengo decimos mas ordenamiento ordenacion parece una mala palabra

Comment: @JackNavaRow ambas son definidas igual [ordenación](https://dle.rae.es/ordenación) y [ordenamiento](https://dle.rae.es/ordenamiento) _Acción y efecto de ordenar_. A mí en el lado este del Atlántico lo de _ordenamiento_ siempre me suena a jurídico. Pero vaya, tanto monta monta tanto

Comment: pues sabia que por ser sensei del sitio de stackoverflow Spanish tendrias un as bajo la manga

Comment: Aunque por los años que tengo me va a ser difícil dejar de hablar de `sort`, estoy de acuerdo con tu propuesta, la única duda, ¿qué pasa con las funciones y las propia herramienta `sort`?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho yo creo que se podría hacer como con `import`, que para casos concretos se puede usar [tag:python-import] y similares ([véase el debate aquí en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4706/83) o el de [\[`order`\] en SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379337/1983854)). De allí podría salir [tag:sql-sort], [tag:python-sort] y [tag:unix-sort], por ejemplo. ¿Qué te parece? Lo suyo es que sean representativas y lógicas, para que no haya que ir haciendo batidas de reetiquetaje constante

Comment: Me parece perfecto @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Propongo que quede como etiqueta principal [ordenamiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordenamiento) y que las otras sean sinónimos de esta.

Comment: ¿Entiendo esta pregunta como apelación a voto popular como en otros casos? En tal caso, habría que añadir respuesta del otro tipo para ver cuál "gana". En cualquier caso, más creo que lo bueno es indicar _por qué_ una u otra.

Comment: Si no es de esta manera, ¿cómo se llegaría a una decisión?

Comment: Una justificación de por qué mejor [tag:ordenamiento] que [tag:ordenación]. Supongo que es por lo que comentaba JackNavaRow de que la primera suena mejor y es más usada en ciertos lugares. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' fui por aca... listo!!!!

Comment: Genial, @gbianchi !! Sería útil que se creara sinónimo de las otras hacia ordenamiento. Es decir, que [tag:ordenacion], [tag:sort] apuntaran a esta [tag:ordenamiento], para así no tener que hacer limpia periódica.

Answer (score 3):

Propongo que quede como etiqueta principal [ordenación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ordenaci%c3%b3n)

Comment: Añado esta respuesta para que se pueda votar por una u otra. Dejaremos esta pregunta en suspenso durante un tiempo para permitir votar a la comunidad.

Comment: Ahora que ha pasado un tiempo prudencial, ¿podríais resolver este tema? No sé si revisáis activamente las preguntas que creé sobre etiquetas o si conviene que os haga un _ping_ para que reviséis. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Propongo que quede como etiqueta principals [sort](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sort)

Comment: [idem](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4831/juntemos-ordenaci%c3%b3n-ordenamiento-sort-y-sorting/4841#comment19821_4838)